# JDBC Retrieve with Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with one to many mapping i.e. Name has one to many relation with Shipping and Payment (**** Ignore Case Sensitivity****)

```
    Table parent has 3 columns    id, name, name_id
    Table shipping has 3 columns  id, shippingName,name_id
    Table payment has 3 columns   id, paymentName, name_id
```

when I execute the below query

```
    SELECT shipping.shippingName,payment.paymentName,parent.name,Parent.name_id
    FROM parent 
    JOIN shipping
    ON  parent.name_id = shipping.name_id
    JOIN payment
    ON  parent.name_id = payment.name_id
    WHERE parent.name_id= '3'
```

The above returns

```
   shipping Name             paymentName          name          name_id
   Fedex                      Credit              AA              3
   Fedex                      Debit               AA              3
   USPS                       Credit              AA              3
   USPS                       Debit               AA              3
```

But what I wanted was

```
   shipping Name             paymentName          name          name_id
   Fedex                      Credit              AA              3
   USPS                       Debit               AA              3
```

Is there a way? Or do I need to set any mapping between shipping and payment table

```
  Shipping Table

   ID        ShippingName    name_id
   1             FEDEX         3
   2             USPS          3

   Payment Table

   ID        PaymentName    name_id
   1         Credit           3
   2         Debit            3

   Parent Table

   ID        name        name_id
   1001        A           1
   1002        B           2
   1003       AA            3
```

Fedex doesnot have payment options..  Parent has one to many with Shipping && Parent has one to many with Payment.. There is no relation between Payment and Shipping
My question was is it even possible to have that resultset I wanted in one database call or should be calling twice with 2 different queries ( Parent+Shipping) (Parent+Payment)

Comment: You will have to change your table design to be more relational if you want to get the desired output.

Comment: instead should I be using 2 different SQL queries with joins i.e. Parent and Shipping && Parent and Payment

Comment: Can you paste the data in all 3 tables here?  looks like the problem is with the data more than the table design.

Comment: these table structure does not have any relationship to show that FEDEX was Credit payment and USPS was Depit payment.  You will have to introduce a one-to-one relationship between Payment and Shipping tables.

Comment: I have posted my way of table structure and query in the Answers section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shipping Table

ID        ShippingName    name_id  Payment_ID
1             FEDEX         3         1
2             USPS          3         2

Payment Table

ID        PaymentName   
1         Credit        
2         Debit        

Parent Table

ID        name        name_id
1001        A           1
1002        B           2
1003       AA           3
```

Query:

```
SELECT shipping.shippingName,payment.paymentName,parent.name,Parent.name_id
FROM parent 
JOIN shipping
ON  parent.name_id = shipping.name_id
JOIN payment
ON  shipping.Payment_ID = payment.ID
WHERE parent.name_id= '3';
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
GROUP BY shipping.shippingName ,payment.paymentName
```

at the end of your query

Comment: It is giving result as this now if I use group by   `      
 Fedex                      Credit              AA              3 //////
   USPS                       Credit              AA              3`

Comment: same result as the one I posted in my question

Comment: **Is there any update that I need to do to my tables ??? shipping and payment both are child tables related to parent **

Comment: there is no relation how you choose one credit and other debit u need something else column to filter

Comment: or you mean the first shipping name will be credit and second shipping name will be debit ?

Answer (score 0):

Where PaymentName IN ('Credit',Debit') AND Name_ID =3